# Retrieve very old builds from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have configured Jenkins to only display up to ten (10) builds. Now I want to go back and find an old build. It was number 1261 and now I am on build 1397. Is there a way to retrieve and view the console log for the old build (`1261`)?

Answer (score 7):

Not unless you have a backup of your Jenkins jobs directory ($JENKINS_HOME/jobs on Unix or %JENKINS_HOME%\jobs on Windows).  The configuration option that sets the number of builds to display doesn't just control how many builds are displayed, but also deletes older builds from the file system to save space.

If you do have a backup, you'll find the console output in `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job name>/<build number>/log`